# Get the list of local functions from a python file into another python file

Tags: python

I have a requirement where I need to parse the functions defined in a python file from another python file.

e.g. I have a python file with following contents:

```
a.py

import os, sys

def function1('text'):
   pass
def function2('text'):
   pass
```

Another file is:
    b.py

```
interested_func = 'function2'

function_list = <code to fetch the functions defined in a.py>
if interested_func in function_list:
   print 'match found'
```

How can I get the functions from a.py into b.py so that I can compare the same with the 'interested_func' data and can do specific task based on the match.

Please note that I have 100s of files with different functions defined inside them, so I do not want to import the file.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: `import`, `dir`, and `callable` are your friends

Comment: Hi Dan, I cannot import the file as I have 100 of such files (similar to a.py) and each file having their own set of functions.

Comment: @AMANDEEPSINGH Why can't you import them? Of course you can import them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I have shared a snippet of the code which I am writing, In my real application, the module to parse (in this case a.py) is stored in a variable (say module = 'a'). In similar way, with each iteration of my code, the variable changes and the python file to parse also changes, can you please suggest me here..

Comment: You can import all the required files and then process them as and when you need to call something from a specific file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `importlib` module:

```
import importlib

obj = importlib.import_module(module)
print(dir(obj))
```

You can read more about importlib over in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

If that doesn't work for you, then you'll probably want to look at some static code analysis tools such as pylint that might give you a clue into how to do this sort of thing. Another place to look would be to check out PyDev's source code and see how it does code analysis.